# ASP.NET JWT authorization returns NotFound

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm working on an api project and need to use jwt, I've configured it on the startup but I get a 404 Notfound response anytime I use [Authorize] on the action. I also noticed that if I use [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")], It will work fine. And I dont want to be using that long statement. Please what could be the cause? Below is my jwt configuration on the startup.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("JWTConfigurations:SecretKey").Value)),
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetSection("JWTConfigurations:Issuer").Value,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = Configuration.GetSection("JWTConfigurations:Audience").Value,
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;  //add this to your code
})
 .AddJwtBearer(...);
```

Or you can auth policy throughout the whole application like this:-

```
  services.AddControllers(opt => {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("Bearer").RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
            opt.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        })
```

So for that, won't need to put `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]` on methods.